# DVCS detect code block movement

Tags: git, version-control, mercurial, dvcs

I'm looking for a version control system that is able to detect if a function is moved inside a file. For example, there is this file "Foo.java" and this contains function "a()", "b()" and "c()".

```
public class Foo
{
    void a()
    {
    }

    void c()
    {
    }

    void b()
    {
    }
}
```

Now if user A changes method "c()" to actually do something:

```
    void c()
    {
        System.out.println("Function c is called");
    }
```

And user B sees the functions should be ordered different and moves "c()" under "b()":

```
public class Foo
{
    void a()
    {
    }

    void b()
    {
    }

    void c()
    {
    }
}
```

Now if they both push to the centralized repository I want the result to be:

```
public class Foo
{
    void a()
    {
    }

    void b()
    {
    }

    void c()
    {
        System.out.println("Function c is called");
    }
}
```

Now what happens is that a conflict occurs and either user A or user B has to do a manual resolve. In my opinion this should be handled automatically or should be displayed in some way. A manual resolve is not a problem if the file is 'not that big' but a file containing 800+ lines is not that clear.

Now I've tested git and mercurial and both cannot resolve this in the way I want. I've used subversion before and know this isn't handled and has some more shortcomings for my uses so I prefer a DVCS.

**EDIT:**
What I (mainly) try to accomplish is to preserve the history of a function. I know that Git for example can show the history of certain lines. However if a function gets moved one can easily confuse the movement as the origin of the function. The DVCS should detect this movement since it must know about the history, like the movement of a file. Linus once said that one should (in case of a movement) only move and not modify a file, so that Git can 'see' the movement. I thought of Git maybe being able to track movements of chunks in a likewise manner.

Comment: If the question is _which DCVS can do that?_, the answer is __None__!

Comment: What you need to look for is a merge tool with this capability, not a DVCS, but I don't know of one.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I asked this a while ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639810/ unfortunately, to my knowledge, there is none.

Comment: @siebz0r - did you tried suggested in topic BC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Mark already said - it isn't problem of SCM per se, but used in it Merge-Compare tool, which all are (more or less) diff-style oriented (i.e work with *strings*, not *logical block of code*)

I can said nothing about mentioned in [(Linux)diff tool that recognizes block movement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5639810/linuxdiff-tool-that-recognizes-block-movement) BeyondCompare, but in Windows-world CompareIT! perfectly detect (and show) moved blocks of strings (and, *to some degree* - moved and changed inside slightly). But:

- CompareIT! costs (some) money
- Doesn't updated long time (from November 2010)
- Can't work for 3-way merge (2-panels diff only)

I heard also *some rumors*, that Conflict Solver in SmartSVN Professional is capable to detect moved blocks of code too

Comment: The link you posted is dead.  Can you correct it or otherwise fix up your post?

Comment: @BlackVegetable - question was deleted. Quote from question (not about BC) "I've seen Plastic SCM and it has a feature called XDiff (or Xmerge) and does exactly what I want. [Here](http://www.plasticscm.com/features/xmerge.aspx) is the feature explained." and up-to-date addition - http://www.semanticmerge.com/